# Backbonejs Click event not function

Tags: json, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have problem with make link with ids from two arrays ...

This view (template) for tables....after click to li event is not function ... Please help me.

```
<script type="text/template" id="table-template">
    <% _.each(tables, function(table) { %>
        <% _.each(table.get("tables"), function(table) { %>


                <li class="tableli" data-table_id="<%= table.id %>">

                    <div class="obrazok"></div>

                    <%= table.name %>

                </li>


        <% }); %>
    <% }); %> 
</script>
```

There is menus template :

```
<script type="text/template" id="menu-template">
    <% _.each(menus, function(menu) { %>
        <% _.each(menu.get("menus"), function(menu) { %>


            <li class="menucls" data-menu_id="<%= menu.id %>">

                <%= menu.name %>

            </li>


        <% }); %>    
    <% }); %>
</script>
```

My collections...

```
//====
//! Tables 
//====
var Tables = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'api/menus_and_tables.json'
});


//====
//! Menus 
//====
var Menus = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'api/menus_and_tables.json'
});
```

My json :

```
{
     "id" : 1,
 "tables" : [{
                 "name": "Table 1",
                 "id": 1
             }],
  "menus" : [{
                 "name": "Main Menu",
                 "id": 1

             }]
}
```

**My First Tables View :**

```
 var TablesView = Backbone.View.extend({       

    events: {
      "click li.tableli" : "openMenuItem"
    },

    openMenuItem: function(e){
      currentLink = $(e.currentTarget);
      tableId = currentLink.data('table_id');
      app.navigate("table/" + tableId + "/menus");
      console.log("table/" + tableId + "/menus");
    },  

        initialize:function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render:function () {
        var that = this;
        var tables = new Tables();
        tables.fetch({
            success: function (tables) {
            var template = _.template($('#table-template').html(), {tables: tables.models});
              that.$el.html(template);
            }
        })
    }             
});
```

**My second Menus View :**

```
var MenusView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
      "click li.menucls" : "openMenuItem"
    },

    openMenuItem: function(e){
      currentLink = $(e.currentTarget);
      menuId = currentLink.data('menu_id');
      console.log("menuId: " + menuId );
    },     

    initialize:function () {
    this.render();
    },
    render:function () {
        var that = this;
        var menus = new Menus();
        menus.fetch({
            success: function (menus) {
            var template = _.template($('#menu-template').html(), {menus: menus.models});
              that.$el.html(template);
            }
        })
    }             
});
```

all is rendered to my content div :

```
<header class="header"></header>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="content" class="span12>">


            <!-  There is rendered content  ->


        </div>        
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

Comment: I edited, You can use if it was useful for you

Comment: Yes I have new question but I don't want from you more information about this new thing.... only about old because I do not bother you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I could found a lot of time to anwser you. I will put here some code. Fistly, index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Backbone.js</title>
  <script src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="underscore.js"></script>
  <script src="backbone.js"></script>
  <script src="menu_bar_collections.js"></script>
  <script src="menu_bar_table.js"></script>
  <script src="menu_bar_menus.js"></script>
<script type="text/template" id="table-template">
    <% _.each(tables, function(table) { %>
        <% _.each(table.get("tables"), function(table) { %>


                <li class="tableli" data-table_id="<%= table.id %>">

                    <div class="obrazok"></div>

                    <%= table.name %>

                </li>


        <% }); %>
    <% }); %> 
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="menu-template">
    <% _.each(menus, function(menu) { %>
        <% _.each(menu.get("menus"), function(menu) { %>


            <li class="menucls" data-menu_id="<%= menu.id %>">

                <%= menu.name %>

            </li>


        <% }); %>    
    <% }); %>
</script>  
<script>
$(function(){

var menuView = new MenusView()
menuView.render()
var tableView = new TablesView()
tableView.render()

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="content_to_menu"></div>
  <div id="content_to_table"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I didn't change your collections. But I changed view:

```
var MenusView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#content_to_menu',

    events: {
      "click li.menucls" : "openMenuItem"
    },

    openMenuItem: function(e){
      currentLink = $(e.currentTarget);
      menuId = currentLink.data('menu_id');
      alert("menuId: " + menuId );
    },     

    initialize:function () {
    this.render();
    },
    render:function () {
        var that = this;
        var menus = new Menus();
        menus.fetch({
            success: function (menus) {
            var template = _.template($('#menu-template').html(), {menus: menus.models});
              that.$el.html(template);
            }
        })
    }             
});
```

and table view:

```
var TablesView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#content_to_table',

    events: {
      "click li.tableli" : "openMenuItem"
    },

    openMenuItem: function(e){
      currentLink = $(e.currentTarget);
      tableId = currentLink.data('table_id');
      alert("tableId: " + tableId);
    },     
        initialize:function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render:function () {
        var that = this;
        var tables = new Tables();
        tables.fetch({
            success: function (tables) {
            var template = _.template($('#table-template').html(), {tables: tables.models});
              that.$el.html(template);
            }
        })
    }             
});
```

I hope, it will help you, good luck!

Comment: Hi Friend !! Thanks for answer but now I have this notice [Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'data' ]

Comment: oops i have forget about $, add changes like this `menuId= $(e.currentTarget).data('menu_id')'

Comment: Thanks for care but I don't know why there is next notice Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$el' of undefined

Comment: when you call your `CategoriesView` did you set `el`, if not do it

Comment: Sry I'm novie in backbone....I have el stored... But there is still same notice... Will I use my template in html after that ?

Comment: i guess, your mistake is here: inside intialize `render(this)`, and  inside loop `render()` . you must call render without this, and add  changes inside render function `that = this`

Comment: you can call render with param, but you have to take the param into accoun all the time

Comment: I have already edited code without mistakes ... But How can I make now  link with two is's ? I mean how Can I load id from table and menu together ?Thank you very much

Comment: Ulugbek very thank you for help me !!! I have now again edited code and I deleted link from template and assign event to li .... Now my console is without errors but after click to li is nothing happend.

Comment: Thank you very very much World with peoples like you is much better :)...I have after apply you code console error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined But this I will do myself. I see you code is correct. Again very thank you !!!

Comment: I have tableId and menuId in console thank you !! But When I click to other view in header and after that click to table link (table view again) this function is not working. How can I always get this function ?

Comment: When I use el in my views nothning is rendered again... When I do not use this el my views is rendered always when I click to one item in my menu ... When I use el page is rendered only once ...

Comment: Thanks for your care but I saw this mistake and is already edited... your code is working but when I will use el in views I can't navigate on this app with my menu in header where is only html links ...
example : <a href="#tables">, <a href="#menus">, <a href="#orders">

Comment: Now is updated my views, all is rendered into id="content" .... In header I have navigation to #tables, #menus, #orders ...(this is working properly) I open /#tables and in header menu I click to orders ... orders is rendered but when I again click to tables, tables is rendered but in console I can't see function ....